Problems with LSTM: Training vs Validation Loss Graph Fluctuations
I am trying to make an LSTM to predict the angles of the double pendulum. Although the results I got are promising, I am concerned about the training/validation loss graph that I generated. In this graph, as attached below, you can see that the validation loss is under the training loss and fluctuates heavily. I've tried experimenting with batch size, learning rate, weight initialization, etc., but I am not able to figure out what is wrong.
Training/Validation Loss Graph
I have tried increasing the batch size, decreasing the learning rate, changing the weight initalization from Xavier to Kaiming, reducing bias variability. I have also tried increasing the sequence length. I have checked all my data preprocessing and everything seems to be processed and scaled correctly. Early stopping was already implemented, dropout only made the fluctuations worse when I tried it.
# Differential equation solver
def f(r, t, L1, L2):
    theta1 = r[0]
    omega1 = r[1]
    theta2 = r[2]
    omega2 = r[3]

    ftheta1 = omega1
    fomega1 = (-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * np.sin(theta1) - m2 * g * np.sin(theta1 - 2 * theta2) - 2 * np.sin(theta1 - theta2) * m2 * 
               (omega2**2 * L2 + omega1**2 * L1 * np.cos(theta1 - theta2))) / (L1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * np.cos(2 * theta1 - 2 * theta2)))

    ftheta2 = omega2
    fomega2 = (2 * np.sin(theta1 - theta2) * (omega1**2 * L1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * np.cos(theta1) + omega2**2 * L2 * m2 * 
                                           np.cos(theta1 - theta2))) / (L2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * np.cos(2 * theta1 - 2 * theta2)))

    return array([ftheta1, fomega1, ftheta2, fomega2], float)

# Generate pendulum data
a = 0.0
b = 1000
N = 1000000
h = (b - a) / N

tpoints = np.arange(a, b, h)
theta1_points = np.zeros_like(tpoints)
theta2_points = np.zeros_like(tpoints)

q = np.array([np.pi / 3, 0, np.pi / 2, 0], float)

for i, t in enumerate(tpoints):
    theta1_points[i] = q[0] * 180 / np.pi
    theta2_points[i] = q[2] * 180 / np.pi

    k1 = h * f(q, t, L1, L2)
    k2 = h * f(q + 0.5 * k1, t + 0.5 * h, L1, L2)
    k3 = h * f(q + 0.5 * k2, t + 0.5 * h, L1, L2)
    k4 = h * f(q + k3, t + h, L1, L2)
    q += (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6

data = np.stack((theta1_points, theta2_points), axis=1)

print("Raw Data Range")
print("Theta1: min =", theta1_points.min(), ", max =", theta1_points.max())
print("Theta2: min =", theta2_points.min(), ", max =", theta2_points.max())


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

print("Normalized Data Range")
print("Min =", data.min(), ", Max =", data.max())

I get my data here using the Runge Kutta 4th order method to solve the differential equations and get the angles for training. This also includes my preprocessing with scaling and transforming the data.
SEQ_LENGTH = 100
X, y = create_sequences(data, SEQ_LENGTH)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
X_test = torch.tensor(X_test, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
y_test = torch.tensor(y_test, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)

train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_layer_size, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_layer_size, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        last_time_step = lstm_out[:, -1, :]
        y_pred = self.linear(last_time_step)
        return y_pred

input_size = 2
hidden_layer_size = 50  # Increased hidden layer size
output_size = 2

model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_layer_size, output_size).to(device)

# Initialize weights and biases
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if 'weight' in name:
         nn.init.kaiming_normal_(param, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
    elif 'bias' in name:
        nn.init.uniform_(param, -0.1, 0.1)

loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0005)  # Reduced learning rate

train_losses = []
test_losses = []

PATIENCE = 10

These are the initializations I used, and I got the graph that is pasted above. I dont believe the model is overfitting, but something else is definitely wrong.
Again, I'm not entirely sure what effect these fluctuations have on my results, as I was able to get an RMSE of 0.000198459987412206 and an r^2 of 0.99999924366113.
How to fix this issue?

This might not be an "issue" as fluctuations are expected, especially since your dataset is small
